# Getting media:thumbnail from RSS using simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, rss, media, feed

I want to get media:thumbnail url from this RSS. It's a wordpress blog:

http://blog.khayyamkar.ir/category/news/feed/

I did some research and found this solution:

https://www.sitepoint.com/parsing-xml-with-simplexml/

**But thumbnail attribute is always NULL!** and I cannot find the problem

> **UPDATE**: -> 'group' was a miss understanding.
>
> the new code is this. But it's a  "object(SimpleXMLElement)[33]" and I don't know how to extract Url:
>
> $item->children($namespace['media'])

This is my code:

```
$url = $this->config->config['wp_news_feed'];
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$namespace = $xml->getNamespaces(true);

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item)
{    
    // $group = $item->children($namespace['media'])->group;
       $group = $item->children($namespace['media']);
    var_dump($group->thumbnail);// <------ This is object(SimpleXMLElement)[32]
}
```

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-6432 how to access attributes.

Answer (score 0):

> But thumbnail attribute is always NULL! and I cannot find the problem

Because there is no `<group>` element in the first item. To be more precise, there is not even the string 'group' contained anywhere in the XML!

Also 'thumbnail' is an element, not an attribute.

Comment: Then how can I get the thumbnail url?

Comment: You are right. That was my mistake. I corrected this but now I I get a SimpleXMLElement and cannot see it's content using var_dump!

Comment: I don't think var_dump() plays well with SimpleXMLElement objects.